# Java: Edit objects without type the name

Tags: java, object

in some programming languages you can say something like this:

```
do with button1 {
    setName("Button");
    setVisible(true);
    ...
}
```

I mean you said that the next (between {}) is for an component and so you don't need to type the name befor, like this

```
button1.setName("Button");
button1.setVisible(true);
...
```

**My question is now can I do something like that in Java?**

Moritz

PS: I know that the examples don't work. They are only for demonstration.

Comment: Java does not support that. There are lambdas, but it would make sense to apply a lambda to one button.

Comment: I think You can create your own `OwnClass` class and extend for `OriginalClass` and add repeatable features by default. I don;t know if Your question is curiosity or you want to have cleaned code in other class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something that looks like the thing you want is [*method chaining*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining):

```
new Button()
    .setName("myButton")
    .setVisible(true)
    .setPreferredSize(200, 100);
```

The condition to achieve something like that is that the method returns the instance it is performing on:

```
class Button {

    public Button setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        return this;
    }
}
```

This is often used in combination with the *builder pattern*.

---

*It looks like you want to do that with Swing elements like `JButton`, but unfortunately, those components do not use method chaining.*

Answer (score 3):

There is not *exactly* that in Java, but there is something similar.

#### Builder Pattern

It looks like this:

```
Button button1 = new ButtonBuilder()
                     .setName("Button")
                     .setVisible(true)
                     ...
                     .build();
```

Obviously this can only be used when you initialise objects.

For an example of a Builder Pattern implementation, just search on Google! I found this: https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/builder/java/2

Answer (score 0):

There is **no such syntax in Java**.

You have to specify the object you want to operate on for each method call.

Answer (score 0):

When you create your own objects, you can have all your set methods return themselves and then call the next method...

Answer (score 0):

What you show is a fluent API.
It may be used for builders but also to simply chain function/method invocations on a object.

This is not a feature that works only for specific languages.
It may indeed work for any language that relies on the `Object` paradigm.
But to use it, the specific API that you are using has to provide this feature, that is, providing methods that return the object itself.
In the case of Java Button, Swing as JavaFx don't provide a fluent API for this class.
So you cannot use a fluent builder or methods out of the box.
Indeed, you have to implement it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that in Java, however, for objects you create you can use chaining to get a similar look and feel to some extent.

```
public class MyClass
{
    private String name;
    private int value;
    private MyClass parent;
    private MyOtherClass thing;

    public MyClass setName(String _name)
    {
        name = _name;
        return this;
    }

    public MyClass setValue(int _value)
    {
        value = _value;
        return this;
    }

    public MyClass setParent(MyClass _parent)
    {
        parent = _parent;
        return this;
    }

    public MyOtherClass setThing(MyOtherClass _thing)
    {
        thing = _thing;
        return this;
    }

    // and some getters would likely be defined too, but I'll not list them here
}
```

Then, to use it, you could do something like...

```
class A
{
    public void f(MyClass o)
    {
        o
            .setName("Me")
            .setValue(1)
            .setParent(new MyClass())
            .setThing(new MyOtherClass())
        ;
    }
}
```

I actually like this style and use it in some of my own code. It makes the code easier to read, and I think it is cleaner looking.

This doesn't do quite the same thing as your example, but it fulfills a lot of the underlying desire to reduce redundancy.

Answer (score 0):

None of the other answers so far addressed the ambiguity that this syntax creates.

If you write a method without prefixing the instance like in `setName("Button");`, this means to implicitly call `this.setName("Button");` (or `MyClass.setName("Button");` if my class had a static method of that name).

Your proposed syntax extension would add to the ambiguity of `setName("Button");` meaning `this.setName("Button");` or `MyClass.setName("Button");` or now also `button1.setName("Button");`.

Of course, such an ambiguity could be resolved by defining a priority rule, e.g. to first look for `button1.setName("Button");` and then for `this.setName("Button");`. But all such implicit rules make reading and understanding such a piece of code more difficult. The more explicitly some piece of code tells me what it does, the better.

Personally, even if Java allowed this syntax, I'd never use it nor encourage my co-workers to use it.

By the way, I typically create JButtons based on Actions already carrying the name and the icon, so I hardly ever set a button's name.